# Make Gem::Specification.find_by_name return correct gem version

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a ruby gem (let's call it `my_gem`) that exposes an executable (let's call it `my_exe`).  When I add `gem "my_gem", "0.0.1"` to the Gemfile of an application and run `bundle exec my_exe`, I correctly get a gem spec for version 0.0.1 when I invoke `Gem::Specification.find_by_name("my_gem")`.

I need this executable to work without bundler being involved.  When I execute

`my_gem _0.0.1_`

and look at the value of `Gem::Specification.find_by_name("my_gem")`, I get the spec back for the latest installed version of `my_gem` on the system.

How do I get `Gem::Specification.find_by_name` to return the gem spec that corresponds to the value I pass to the exectuable?

**Update**

There's a piece of info I forgot to mention.  I can't modify the code that calls `Gem::Specification.find_by_name("my_gem")`.  That particular line of code is invoked in a 3rd party library that `my_exe` calls.  (The library is RuboCop and here's where RuboCop tries to load the spec (https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/v0.55.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb#L186) I'm trying to setup the environment so `Gem::Specification.find_by_name("my_gem")` returns the spec for the version of `my_gem` which is on the `$LOAD_PATH`.  There must be a way to do it since `bundler` is able to make it happen.

Comment: You mean `Gem::Specification.find_by_name("my_gem", "= 0.0.1")`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Gem::Specification.find_by_name("my_gem", "0.0.1")
```

If a spec matching the requirement can't be found, an error will be raised. Check out https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html#find_by_name-method

**Update**

Updating my answer in response to your update.

You might be better saying what your job to be done is on a higher level. Bundler is the best tool for package management, you really don't want to do it yourself. Without knowing what you're doing or how you're trying to implement your code, perhaps you could inline Bundler

```
require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile 
  gem 'my-gem', '0.0.1'
end

# Do my work
```

Comment: See https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html#find_by_name-method

Comment: AND [`Gem::Requirement`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Requirement.html) but maybe a tiny bit of content to the answer would be nice

Comment: Thank for the response.  I updated to the question to clarify.